# perform(click()) is not working in Android 11 but working in Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, cucumber, android-espresso, android-11

I have one test case where I want to click fragment button which will navigate me to different screen.

This is my test case in feature file.

```
@abc
  Scenario: As a RM, I should be able to see accepted on coming to admin approval screen
    Given User is at XYZ screen for scenario "approved"
    And User is able to see that verification is accepted
    When User clicks on next button
    Then User will be navigated to abc screen
```

When "User clicks on next button" test case is executed this method will call with the button id.

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.add_button))
            .perform(ViewActions.click())
```

And after that "Then" situation will execute with this method where I'm navigating to different fragment.

```
 /**
   * Match destination to which user will be navigated.
   * Assert that mock nav controller has action for destination.
   * 
   * @param id : This is fragment action id
   */
  fun matchIntendedDestination(id: Int) {
    SystemClock.sleep(1000)
    val idCapture = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Int::class.java)
    Mockito.verify(BaseHelper.getMockNavController()).navigate(idCapture.capture())
    Assert.assertEquals(id, idCapture.value)
  }
```

Gradle version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
```

Espresso libraries

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.1.0')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-android:4.3.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.6.0'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.4'
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.3.3"
```

And getting this error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
navController.navigate(<Capturing argument>);
-> at com.rupeek.loanreleaseapp.helper.ReleaseRejectionHelper.matchIntendedDestination(ReleaseRejectionHelper.kt:117)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

But the problem is this code is executing successfully in android 10 but not in Android 11.
Can anyone please help me what I'm missing here for Android 11. I have also checked with updating all the libraries.

And when I debugged the code I found that perform(click()) is not calling anything in the  fragment.

Comment: any error logs?

Comment: @QAMAR updated my question with error logs

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Android 11. After trying so many options I found this solution for me. You can try this by creating a custom class.

create a custom click action to force click on it instead:

```
public static ViewAction forceClick() {
return new ViewAction() {
    @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return allOf(isClickable(), isEnabled(), isDisplayed());
    }

    @Override public String getDescription() {
        return "force click";
    }

    @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        view.performClick(); // perform click without checking view coordinates.
        uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
    }
};
```

}

Then use it on a button or any view that has a click listener attached to it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.add_button)).perform(forceClick());
```